# Funciones se sobreejecuta

Tags: javascript

Me encuentro realizando una trivia. El comienzo de este código contiene dos funciones **`pedirNombre`** y **`triviaA`** , que es un eventListener de **`botonA`**.

Hasta el momento he logrado que **`triviaA`** no se sobreponga a la función
**`pedirNombre`** con el método `done()` en la línea 56. Sin embargo, se sigue ejecutando muy pronto.

Por ello, quiero saber si estoy realizando un uso correcto del método. Por otro lado, al presionar el botonA y ejecutarse la función, el inspector devuelve que que **`pregunta[i]`** no está definido, ni tampoco **`pregunta`**

```js
//ELEMENTOS GLOBALES
let preguntas_respuestas = [
    {
        p: '¿Qué significa tomarse la pastilla roja?',
        r: ['Liberarse de la realidad virtual de matrix y dirigirse al mundo real', ' respuesta incorrecta ', ' respuesta incorrecta']
    },
    {
        p: '¿Cuál es el nombre real de Neo?',
        r: ['Thomas', 'respuesta incorrecta', 'respuesta incorrecta']            
    }, 
    {
        p: '¿Qué actriz interpretó a Trinity?',
        r: ['Carrie Anne Moss', 'respuesta incorrecta', 'respuesta incorrecta']            
    },
    {
        p: '¿Cómo se llama el aerodeslizador de transporte de Morfeo?',
        r:['Nebuchadnezzar', 'respuesta incrrecta', 'respuesta incorrecta']            
    }
]

let contenedor = document.getElementById('contenedor')
let bienvenida = document.querySelector('.bienvenida')
let divBotones = document.createElement('div')
    divBotones.setAttribute('id', 'divBotones')
let botonA = document.createElement('button')
    botonA.innerText = 'Preguntas de tipo A'    
let botonB = document.createElement('button')
    botonB.innerText = 'Preguntas de tipo B'
    
let pedirNombre = (nombre) => {
    nombre = prompt('Bienvenidx \n ¿Cuál es tu nombre?')
    let saludo = bienvenida
    if(nombre !== null ){
        bienvenida.innerText = `Hola ${nombre.toUpperCase()}, ¿listx para jugar?`
    } else {
        bienvenida.innerText = 'Hola Anonimx, ¿listx para jugar?'
    } 
    contenedor.appendChild(divBotones)
    divBotones.append(botonA, botonB)
    return saludo
}
pedirNombre()

//creando una funcion para las preguntas tipo A
let triviaA = (i) =>{
//tomando la pregunta del array de preguntas 
let pregunta = preguntas_respuestas[i]
//colocar la pregunta dentro del html
let p_html = `<h5>${pregunta[i].p}</h5>`
bienvenida.innerHTML = p_html
}

//agregar event listener al boton A
botonA.addEventListener('click', triviaA)
//ejecutar funcion luego de que funcion pedirNombre termine
triviaA(0).done(pedirNombre)
```

```css
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body{
    background-color: #4d09cd;
    
}

#contenedor{
    width: 400px;
    height: 450px;
    background-color: rgb(228, 233, 88);  
    border-radius: 1rem;
   box-shadow: 10px 10px black;
   padding: 5%;
   position: relative;
   top: 20rem;
   left: 20rem;
   overflow: auto;   
}

.bienvenida{
    font-size: 25px;
    text-align: left;
    
}
.botonA, .botonB{
    padding: 0.5rem ;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-color: #4d09cd;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
}

#divBotones button{
    font-size: large;
    padding: 0.5rem ;
    border-radius: 1rem;
    background-color: #4d09cd;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    display: inline-block;
}

.correcto{
    padding: .5rem;
    background-color: rgb(145, 218, 34);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
.incorrecto{
    padding: .5rem;
    background-color: rgb(188, 21, 21);
    border-radius: 1rem;
    text-align: center;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
}
.circulo{
    background-color: rgb(145, 218, 34);
    border-radius: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Trivia</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="#" type="image/x-icon">
  </head>
  <body>
    <main>
    <div id="contenedor">
      <h5 class="bienvenida"></h5>
        
        
        
    </div>
  </main>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: la función pedir nombre no tiene llave de apertura ni de cierre en la función, primero arregla eso.

Comment: @Osaskoh , gracias por tu respuesta. Podrías, por favor, señalarme en qué parte no se encuentran las llaves de apertura ni de cierre de esa funcion?

Comment: pues las llaves van asi:  pedirnombre(){     codigo a ejecutar  }   tu deberías saber que es lo que necesita estar dentro de las llaves y que no, recuerda que cuando mandas a llamar esa función se va a ejecutar el código comprendido entre las 2 llaves